# common word in a text

Tags: java, hadoop

I am trying to find out the most common word in a text using Hadoop. Hadoop is is a framework that allows for the distributed processing of large data sets across clusters of computers.

I know this can be done easily by using the Unix command :  `job: sort -n -k2 txtname | tail`. But this doesn't scale to large datasets. So I'm trying to break the problem up and then combine the results.

Here is my `WordCount` class:

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
    import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
    import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
    import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
    import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

    public class WordCount {
      public static void runJob(String[] input, String output) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = new Job(conf);
        job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);

        job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        Path outputPath = new Path(output);
        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, StringUtils.join(input, ","));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outputPath);
        outputPath.getFileSystem(conf).delete(outputPath,true);
        job.waitForCompletion(true);
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        runJob(Arrays.copyOfRange(args, 0, args.length-1), args[args.length-1]);
      }
    }
```

I understand that I need to make an additional job to work in parallel with the map reduce classes of the word count.

Here is my `TokenizerMapper` class:

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.StringTokenizer;
    import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
    import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

    public class TokenizerMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable> { 
      private final IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
      private Text data = new Text();

      public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString(), "-- \t\n\r\f,.:;?![]'\"");

        while (itr.hasMoreTokens())  {
          data.set(itr.nextToken().toLowerCase());
          context.write(data, one);
        }
      }
    }
```

Here is my `IntSumReducer` class:

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
    import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

    public class IntSumReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
      private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();
      public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)

      throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int sum = 0;

        for (IntWritable value : values) {
          // TODO: complete code here
          sum+=value.get();
        }

        result.set(sum);

        // TODO: complete code here

        if (sum>3) {
          context.write(key,result);
        }
      }
    }
```

What i need to do is define another map and reduce class that will work in parallel with this current one. The most occurring words will appear, here is what i have for reduce class so far:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.Context;

public class reducer2 extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
  int max_sum =0;
  Text max_occured_key = new Text();

  private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

  public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)

  throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    int sum = 0;

    for (IntWritable value : values) {
      // TODO: complete code here
      sum+=value.get();
    }

    if (sum >max_sum) {
      max_sum = sum;
      max_occured_key.set(key);
    }

    context.write(max_occured_key, new IntWritable(max_sum));

    //result.set(sum);

    // TODO: complete code here

    /*
    if (sum>3) {
      context.write(key,result);
    }
    */
  }

  protected void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    context.write(max_occured_key, new IntWritable(max_sum));
  }
}
```

The code for `mapper2`:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.Context;

public class mapper2 {
  private final IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
  private Text data = new Text();

  public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString(), "-- \t\n\r\f,.:;?![]'\"");
    int count =0;

    while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {    
      //data.set(itr.nextToken().toLowerCase());          
      context.write(data, one);
    }
  }
}
```

I've also edited the `WordCount` class so that two jobs can run at the same time:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class WordCount {
  public static void runJob(String[] input, String output) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = new Job(conf);
    job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);

    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    Path outputPath = new Path(output);
    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, StringUtils.join(input, ","));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outputPath);
    outputPath.getFileSystem(conf).delete(outputPath,true);
    job.waitForCompletion(true);

    Job job2 = new Job(conf);
    job2.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);

    job2.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job2.setReducerClass(reducer2.class);
    job2.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job2.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    Path outputPath2 = new Path(output);
    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, StringUtils.join(input, ","));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outputPath);
    outputPath.getFileSystem(conf).delete(outputPath,true);
    job.waitForCompletion(true);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       runJob(Arrays.copyOfRange(args, 0, args.length-1), args[args.length-1]);
  }
}
```

How do I find out the most common word in a text using hadoop?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I am trying to find out the most common word in a text using hadoop.and print it

Answer (score 0):

This is the canonical word count problem, you can google and find any number of solutions for basic word count. Then you have just one more step to do: return the word with the largest count.

How to do that?

If the amount of data is not too large and you can afford to use a single reducer then set the number of reducers to 1. Inside your reduce keep a local variable that remembers which of the groups (i.e. words) has/have the highest count(s). Then write that result to a file in HDFS.

If the amount of data precludes using a single reducer then you just have one extra step beyond the first one mentioned above: you need to find the highest count across all of the reducers. You can do that by either a global counter or by writing each of the individual max words to their own (tiny) file in hdfs and have a post processing step (probably a linux script) to then parse and obtain the max of the maxes.  Alternatively you could have yet another map/reduce job find it - but that would be a bit of overkill for that small/ simple operation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mistaken that `sort -n -k2` will not work at scale in this case. WordCount will probably never output on the order of thousands or tens of thousands of words. This is simply due to the cardinality of most natural languages. So, even if you have 10 Petabytes of data, it will still be distilled down into at most 10,000 or 20,000 words (albeit the counts are high).

First, have your WordCount job run on the data. Then, use some bash to pull the top N out.

```
hadoop fs -cat /output/of/wordcount/part* | sort -n -k2 | tail -n20
```

---

If for some reason you are getting a ton of words out of wordcount (i.e., you aren't doing it on natural language)...

Have two MapReduce jobs:

1. WordCount: counts all the words (pretty much the example exactly)
2. TopN: A MapReduce job that finds the top N of something (here are some examples: [source code](https://github.com/adamjshook/mapreducepatterns/blob/master/MRDP/src/main/java/mrdp/ch3/TopTenDriver.java), [blog post](http://blog.gopivotal.com/products/how-hadoop-mapreduce-can-transform-how-you-build-top-ten-lists))

Have the output of WordCount write to HDFS. Then, have TopN read that output. This is called job chaining and there are a number of ways to solve this problem: oozie, bash scripts, firing two jobs from your driver, etc.

The reason you need two jobs is you are doing two aggregations: one is word count, and the second is topN. Typically in MapReduce each aggregation requires its own MapReduce job.